# Document Management in Drupal 8

Tags: drupal, alfresco, drupal-8, document-management

Looking for a good document management solution in Drupal 8. I have seen some modules but none of them seem to be active. I've also considered Alfresco-Drupal integration but the drupal module seems to be unmaintained as well. What other solutions available?

I would like the following features:

- doc storage, folders
- versioning (major, minor)
- check in/checkout
- granular permissions
- approval workflow (nice to have)

Looked at the following modules:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/document_library
- https://www.drupal.org/project/document
- https://www.drupal.org/project/filedepot
- https://www.drupal.org/project/alfresco
- https://www.drupal.org/project/cmis

Comment: Developing something on your own, or paying someone else to do it, would you consider these options?

Comment: @Lista we are trying to stay away from too much custom development (except for the theme) but it seems it might be our only option.

Answer (score 3):

What about the standard CMIS module? https://www.drupal.org/project/cmis ?

Comment: I was considering this but the 8.x branch is still in dev. We are trying to use drupal 8

Comment: It's probably not the answer that you expect. But if you can, I'll clearly wait for this module.

Answer (score 1):

This question might not be active anymore, but you might want to try Vardoc.
https://www.drupal.org/project/vardoc